# A question on the minimal ordinal for ZFC

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

If ZF has a standard model there is a least ordinal $\sigma$ such that $L_{\sigma}$ is a model of ZFC. What is $\sigma$ called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not have any particular name or notation: it is just ''the height of the minimal model of set theory''

Comment: I thought as much. Wikipedia misleadingly calls it an $unprovable \ ordinal $. Perhaps one should start calling it $ the \ Cohen \ ordinal $.

Comment: ``The Cohen ordinal'' would be a misattribution: John Shepherdson also identified the ordinal more than a decade earlier in one of three JSL articles in the late forties (I forget which one) analysing the Goedel model. I doubt he was alone. Mostowski?

Comment: I knew about Shepherdson, who I thought wrote in the early fifties. If I remember correctly, though, Cohen made some improvements in describing the minimal model. Nevertheless, a $Shepherdson \ ordinal$ would be fine. A reference to Mostowski on this would be welcome.